# Swipe to go back in Angular+Cordova based IOS app

Tags: javascript, html, ios, angular, cordova

I have developed an IOS application in angular and packaging is done using cordova. Now for going back i have added a back button on top and applied routing on click of back, There are many applications which have the back feature by swiping left to right, like it is in instagram. Is there any way, i can implement it in my application?